# Combine fno-rtti lib and rtti lib while compiling?

Tags: c++, boost, llvm, rtti

I'm using some LLVM static libs and boost::program_options in my test app. The problem is that source code that uses LLVM libs should be compiled with `-fno-rtti` (`llvm-config -cxxflags` return it in output

```
$ ./llvm-config --cxxflags
-I/Users/user/Documents/dev/src/llvm/installed_local/include  -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-common -Woverloaded-virtual -Wcast-qual
```

) but boost::program_options requires RTTI via `boost::any`:

```
/softdev/boost-1.56/include/boost/any.hpp:149:48: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
            return content ? content->type() : typeid(void);
```

Compile cmd for my app:

```
clang++ `${LLVM_BIN}/llvm-config --cxxflags` -I${LLVM_INCLUDE} -I${CLANG_INCLUDE} -I/softdev/boost-1.56/include -c ./lib_linker.cpp -o ./lib_linker_x86_64.o
```

What should i do in order to compile my app?

**PS. The same problem with exceptions** - LLVM turns off exceptions with `-fno-exceptions` but program_options requires them:

```
/softdev/boost-1.56/include/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp:355:20: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
            return typeid(T);
```

Comment: for exception, there is no prevention from using `-fexception` to compile your own project at all, simply remove/replace `-fno-exception` will be enough; a library is compiled w/o exception has no influence on your client code. for rtti, i guess most of the time you still don't use rtti for llvm Objects. You might need some scripts to handle cxxflags string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recompile LLVM with RTTI and exceptions enabled.

Comment: i've found boost::program_options patch but it seems to be not full: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10347. So i had to recompile LLVM with `--enable-expensive-checks`

Comment: This is surely not the flag which enabled RTTI and exceptions. Your LLVM installation will be *very* slowed by additional checks which does not make any sense.

Comment: ok how can i recompile LLVM with RTTI support and without expensive checks?

Comment: i was able to do it using only `REQUIRES_RTTI=1` env var while building